# How to prove this probability theory expectation problem?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ only own values from the set $\left\{ {-n, -n+1, \ldots, -1}\right\}$ and the values may not be equally possible. Prove that then:
$$E(X)=-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P(X \leq -i)$$

Any tips are welcome, this should be solvable using only the definition of the expectation and its basic properties.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Start by writing out the expectation:
$$
\mathbb{E}[X]=\sum_{i=-n}^{-1}i\,P(X=i)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\,P(X=-i).\tag{1}
$$
Now, note that
$$
P(X\leq -i)=P(X=-n)+P(X=-n+1)+\cdots+P(X=-i),
$$
and group like terms in the expression you were given to rewrite it in the form $(1)$.

In particular: for how many $j$ does the term $P(X=-i)$ occur in $P(X\leq -j)$?